# "Failed to upgrade encrypted tmbootpicker.efi" in Time Machine backups

Tags: time-machine, backup, filevault

I've noticed the error "Failed to upgrade encrypted tmbootpicker.efi: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-50 "Could not find any Apple_Boot corresponding to the encrypted volume..." UserInfo=0x7fdc3cd65580 {NSLocalizedDescription=Could not find any Apple_Boot corresponding to the encrypted volume...}" showing up in the backup logs on my system.

The Time Machine backups *appear* to be finishing without error (I didn't noticed it except for  a widget I use for monitoring backup progress which parses the log files; from the end user perspective, Time Machine just seems to hesitate a bit at the last step of the backup then finish when you just view the animated time icon from Finder.)

System: OS X 10.8, MacBook Pro 13 inch Mid 2010. Time Machine is on an external USB hard disk. Both the MBP and Time Machine drives are encrypted with File Vault 2.

Is this an error that others are seeing, and something that should be worried about?

Is there a way short of wiping and reinstalling from Time Machine backup to verify that the backups are actually valid and working?